# How to understand use-cases in specific scenerio

Tags: drawing, uml, modeling, use-case

I am drawing a diagram of use-case using ArgoUML, I have a scenario in which user can update status but after sign in to the application , in that sense i need to extends update status after sign in or make it a new separate usecase or generalize it.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Login` is not a use case simply because it does not bring any value to the actor. It is a constraint. Just draw the association from `user` to `update status` (use verb substantive, not a concatenated identifier). You can put the `login` association inside the use case.

Ask yourself for a use case: what value does it add to the user? The `login` does not add any value. My value on SO for example is that I can ask question or that I can earn points be answering questions. So they are use cases "ask question" and "answer question".

Comment: lets take the example of stackoverflow , like if user is a actor , he has to login to ask question , then usefull question , downvote for wrong question , so in this we just need to make user a actor and ask_qestion as usecase , to usfull_question vote should be seprate usecase or its kind of <<extend>> from ask_question ?

Comment: No. The login is still a constraint. On SO you have "ask question", "answer question", "vote up", "vote down", "comment answer", "comment question", and so on.

Comment: Exactly. Avoid `<<include>>` and `<<extend>>`. Use cases are not analyzed. They are synthesized.  No functional analysis here, please!

Comment: yes but earning points on answers or questions can be usecase assosiated with users ? or extend from question or answer. Thank you

Comment: Again no: Earning points is not a use case. It's a post condition of "vote up"

Comment: this is what i am saying , voteup and votedown are usecases ? yea ?

Comment: vote up/down ARE use cases. But "earn points" is not a UC, it's a post condition of "vote up". I recommend Bittner/Spence (see on Amanzon; expensive but worth the money)